# Why the strategy in Real-time trading only alert once?

Tags: pine-script

The back test of the following strategy looks perfect, and nearly there are trades every day. However, when it's running on real-time trading, it only trigged one alert since 5 days ago.

**What's wrong with that?**

[image]

[image]
source code

```
//@version=4


// alligator conditions
alligatorBullishEating() => 
    ret = float(0)
    ret := lips > teeth and teeth > jaw ? 1 : na
    ret
    
alligatorBearishEating() => 
    ret = float(0)
    ret := lips < teeth and teeth < jaw ? 1 : na
    ret
    

day_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
day_ema = ema(day_close, 14)
plot(day_ema)

pap = nz(strategy.position_avg_price)
profit = 100*(close - nz(strategy.position_avg_price)) / nz(strategy.position_avg_price) 

        
        
long_condition = crossover(lips,jaw) and close < day_ema
if long_condition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=contracts, comment='B01', alert_message=open_json)


if profit > 1
    strategy.close_all(comment="cls",alert_message=close_json)
  
if profit < -4
    strategy.close_all(comment="SL",alert_message=close_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the use of the security function in this manner is causing repainting on the real time bar. The daily close is recalculating on each new bar that passes as we do not know the daily close until it has occurred. This is giving the strategy look ahead bias on the historical bar as well which gives the illusion of great results, but would require being able to see the future.

To use the daily close the on a lower time frame the best we can do is use yesterdays close, as todays in unknown yet. For this I would recommend using a historical offset in your close calculation, which would look like this:

day_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1])

For consistency, the best practice to call an ema is to use it directly from the security call:

ema = ema(close, 14)

day_ema = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ema[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1])

This way we can establish a daily EMA using confirmed data only which will help to align backtesting with real time results and behave similarly.

Best of luck in your trading and coding my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` on the message box when creating the alert(Alt + A)?

Comment: yes, I added this